# Scala - conditionally sum elements in list

Tags: scala

I am trying to solve a beginner problem with lists but can't find an example to help me get it work. I am given a list of positive and negative integers (AccountHistory) and I need to check if the negative integers in this list have ever exceeded -1000. I expected my code to work with a freshly introduced helper function like this:

```
def checkAccount(account: AccountHistory): Boolean = {
def helper(i: AccountHistory): Int = {
  var total = 0
  i.collect{case x if x < 0 => Math.abs(x) + total}
  return total
}
if (helper(account) >1000) true else false
}
```

But it doesn't work. Please help me find my mistake or problem in wrong approach.

Edit: The pre-given tests include

```
assert(checkAccount(List(10,-5,20)))
assert(!checkAccount(List(-1000,-1)))
```

So if assert expects true then my approach is wrong to solve it like this.

By 'exceeded' I mean <-1000, for any or all elements in a list (like exceeding a credit amount in given period).

Comment: `account.filter(_ < 0).sum < -1000`

Comment: @jwvh I even managed to understand it, I think, but if testing with assert(checkAccount(List(10,-5,20))), then it fails. I don't understand why. If explaining this can be part of the topic, would be good to read it.

Comment: @ktii `assert` assume the return is true and it that case it is false so it fails. i.e. AssertionError

Comment: @ktii; try `assert(checkAccount(List(10,-5,20))==false)` or `assert(checkAccount(List(-811,5,-200)))`

Comment: @jwvh ok I understand assert now but I can't change it. It's a pre-given test. Then my approach to solve this problem like this, was wrong?

Comment: If that `assert` is supposed to succeed then your description of the problem is wrong. No combination of that 3-element `List` will "ever exceeded -1000" (or even 100 for that matter).

Answer (score 3):

```
i.collect{case x if x < 0 => Math.abs(x) + total}
```

In the above code snippet, not **assign back to** `total`, maybe you need:

```
val total = i.filter(_ < 0).map(Math.abs).sum
```

Comment: Still assertion failed. Using assert(checkAccount(List(10,-5,20))). Why?

Comment: seems miss `Math.abs`

Comment: I managed to understand suggested line but as the pre-given assert expects true then I guess my approach was wrong. Currently not seeing how to do it then..

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you're supposed to do:

```
def checkAccount(account: AccountHistory): Boolean = 
  account.forall(_ > -1000)
```

Comment: The pre-given tests still result in error but I am not sure any more if this is part of the original question or it's getting out of scope. I'm sorry if I made a confusing initial description. All answers seem to do part of the work but currently I have not yet reached a solution. If I manage to reach an acceptable solution, I will post it here too, or mark somebody's answer.